# Can't print each iteration in my for loop code correctly

Tags: r, for-loop, iteration, anova

How do I print each iteration for this? It's only printing the first iteration multiple times. Or is this not looping over each column correctly?

edit: just realized I kept specifying the same variable in the anova. But now I can't figure out how to run this anova over each column.

```
CR <- data2[data2$cv == "CR",]
colu <- CR[,5:36]

for (i in colnames(colu)){
  ANOVA <- aov(i ~ block + loc, data=CR)
  ANOVA_SUMMARY <- summary(ANOVA)
  test <- HSD.test(ANOVA , "loc")
  print(test$groups)
}
```

Comment: What's supposed to be changing in the loop? You have the variable `i` but you never use it in the loop body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `reformulate` or `as.formula` to create the formula object used in `aov`. Try,

```
for (i in colnames(colu)){
  ANOVA <- aov(reformulate(c('block', 'loc'), i), data=CR)
  ANOVA_SUMMARY <- summary(ANOVA)
  test <- HSD.test(ANOVA , "loc")
  print(test$groups)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i is not included in your for loop, so it will print result of

```
    aov(days_til_flower ~ block + loc, data=CR)
```

Comment: just realized this and i made edits. Now I'm not sure why it won't run the anova. I am receiving this error: Error in model.frame.default(formula = i ~ block + loc, data = CR, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'block')